# Routing redirection not working properly (Symfony 3)

Tags: symfony, symfony-routing

I have an issue with my application, I have several routes declared on my controller which works properly but I have trouble with one of them.

I used the annotation system to declare the route of this method (like all my routes which works) like this :

```
/**
 * Do something
 *
 * @Route("/synchro", name="app_synchro")
 */
public function synchroAction(Request $request){
    //code here etc...
}
```

I checked it with the `debug:router` command so I know this route exists, I also tried to print `$route` and the value is good but when I made a redirection using :

`return $this->redirectToRoute('app_synchro');`

I encounter a 404 error.

Please, could someone help me to understand the origin of this issue ?

Comment: If you try to access it in production, do you have clear the cache before ?
And what happen if you access the redirected page directly ?

Comment: Hello, thank your for your help.
Yes, I cleared the cache and no I also can't reach the route directly.

Comment: Please give us your real route definition, no errors here

Answer (score 5):

The proper way to redirect is to return it directly like so:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('my_route_name');
```

What you are doing is returning the result code of redirecting...

```
$route= $this->redirectToRoute('my_route_name');
```

So `$route` contains the result of the redirect, which is NOT what you want.

Comment: Hello, Thank for your help.
I made the redirection like you advised but I still got the 404 error. Can you see something else which seems to be wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried using the Debug URL `app_dev.php`. It's described in more detail in this [Reducing KnpPaginatorBundle Database Queries article](https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2017/05/25/reducing-knppaginatorbundle-database-queries/) I wrote. You can also check logs in the `var/logs` folder to see if anything is shown in the logs.